# How to recognize a third paty yaml dump object back- without specifying redundant import statemnets

Tags: python-3.x, pyyaml, flake8

Imagine you have something similar to the following `yaml`:

```yaml
model: !!python/object:Thirdpartyfoo.foo_module.foo_class
     some_attribue: value
```

In addition, assume you already installed package `Thirdpartyfoo` using some pip install or something.

Now you want to get things out of the yaml back into python obeject so you do:

```py
import yaml
with open('foo.yaml') as f:
    dict = yaml.load(f,  yaml.Loader)
```

But after you run it you get error like:

```py
Except ImportError as exc:
                raise ConstructorError("while constructing a Python object", mark,
                        "cannot find module %r (%s)" % (module_name, exc), mark)
        if module_name not in sys.modules:
            raise ConstructorError("while constructing a Python object", mark,
                   "module %r is not imported" % module_name, mark)
            yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: while constructing a Python object
            module 'Thirdpartyfoo.foo_module' is not imported
```

You end up with a very ugly solution for that:

```py
import Thirdpartyfoo.foo_module.foo_class as dummy_import

with open('foo.yaml') as f:
    dict = yaml.load(f,  yaml.Loader)
```

Note that if I won't explicitly mention line `dummy_import` I will get unused import at line ... by `flake8` lint check :)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [YAML documentation](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation), what `yaml.load()` does is that it converts YAML documents to python objects.

> The function `yaml.load()` converts a YAML document to a Python object. `yaml.load()` accepts a byte string, a Unicode string, an open binary file object, or an open text file object.

The reason you're getting this error is that you're loading a data from yaml file that has no proper object to be stored in. As long as you do not import a library in the python runtime environment, it's just a file like any other file on your computer and has no specific value to python. So the only way to fix this issue is that you should `import` the proper class definition to store your data into it, which you just did in the last part. Just importing `Thirdpartyfoo` would do the job as well, cause it loads every definition into the python runtime environment.

Comment: Doing imports like I did need also a line of usage else you get error by python lint, specifically in my case it is `flake8`

Comment: So the point of importing a data from yaml file is to use it, right? And for that you must import the proper library and use some of its features in future time. So `flake8` is doing the right job by telling you that you should use the imported library, unless you're not doing the right thing here.